# Issue with system subroutine and INT signal

Tags: perl

I have an INT signal handler in my Perl script. It will not be executed when the INT is sent while the Perl script is in the middle of a system call. Why?

Consider:

```
$ perl5.12/bin/perl -E "$(cat <<EOF

    \$SIG{INT} = sub {say q(trapped INT); exit};
    say q(sleeping ...);
    system q(sleep 10000); # INT at this point is not caught by Perl.

EOF)"
sleeping ...
```

However, if I replace the system call with a sleep call, it works as expected:

```
$ perl5.12/bin/perl -E "$(cat <<EOF

    \$SIG{INT} = sub {say q(trapped INT); exit};
    say q(sleeping ...);
    sleep 10000; # replaces the system call from above

EOF)"
sleeping ...
trapped INT
```

The Perl version is:

```
$ perl5.12/bin/perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 9 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2010, Larry Wall

Binary build 1204 [294330] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Feb  9 2011 14:48:47
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect whether the `system()` subprocess is killed by `SIGINT` by checking [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3F), like this:

```
use POSIX qw(SIGINT);

sub interrupt {
    say "trapped INT";
    exit;
}

$SIG{INT} = \&interrupt;

say "sleeping";
system ("sleep 100");

if (($? & 127) == SIGINT) {
        interrupt();
} elsif ($?) {
        say "subprocess failed, status $?";
}
```

The `INT` and `QUIT` signals are ignored by perl while the external command is running, see [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 1):

When invoking system(), whatever is being executed has control of the terminal.  Sending any signals to it through keyboard controls will be sent to the process that is executing (in this case the system's sleep command).

Trapping signals and doing something with them in a Perl script only works while that script is running.  To have a trap in Bash you can use `trap "command" signal`:

```
$ perl -e'system("trap \"echo Trapped\" SIGINT; sleep 10");'
^CTrapped
```

Comment: If that were true, the following wouldn't warn in response to ^C: `use IPC::Open3;
$SIG{INT} = sub { warn("INT") };
open3('<&STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR',
   q{perl -e'$SIG{INT}="IGNORE"; sleep 5'});
1 while !waitpid(-1, 0) && $!{EINTR};
`

Comment: As Andy mentioned, the reason the handler isn't called is that `system` sets `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` to `IGNORE` while its running.