# Catch SIGINT when qx or system

Tags: perl

Consider this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Argv;    
use sigtrap 'handler' => \&stop, 'INT';

for (0 .. 10) {
    Argv->new('sleep', '0.5')->system;
}

sub stop { 
    print "\nStopping this damned program!\n" and exit -1;
}
```

I would like to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> at anytime in my program. This does not work even if I try to trap `SIGINT`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806555/issue-with-system-subroutine-and-int-signal) where the solution can written like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Argv;
use POSIX qw(SIGINT);

$SIG{INT} = \&stop;

for (0 .. 10) {
    Argv->new('sleep', '0.5')->qx;
}

sub stop { 
    print "\nStopping this damned program!\n" and exit -1;
}
```